# Get hard disk size without df

Tags: linux, hard-drive, df, proc

How to check a vendor's statement about a hard disk size? `df` shows results partition oriented (including tmpfs), one has to execute it and count label oriented.

How to get in a single command or cat /proc's file the hard disk size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*hdparm*](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm), when invoked with the `-I` switch, displays identification info directly requested from the drive. This includes the drive's size and pretty pretty much everything else you could be interested in.

To display only the drive's size, you can use this command:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdX | grep "device size"
```

A word of caution: *hdparm* requires root access and is a potentially destructive tool. While the `-I` switch is perfectly safe to use, others aren't.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for. I also found the following: `sudo parted -l`... helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods actually, Not all of these programs will be installed by default but all will be easily available on any GNU/Linux distribution:

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -A 15 disk | grep size
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
$ df --total -TH --exclude-type=tmpfs | awk '{print $3}' | tail -n 1
468G
```

`hdparm` and `fdisk -l` have already been mentioned but you could do

```
$ sudo fdisk -l | grep "^Disk /" | gawk '{print $3,$4}'
500.1 GB,
```

Answer (score 1):

While not the easiest to parse, and not recommended for scripting purposes, `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` should give you the information you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to calc without the need of multipling `blocks * block's size` as fdisks's usual result are in blocks, sectors?

Comment: plus, does fdisk consider tmpfs?